# Facebook unable to get all user photos

Tags: android, android-facebook

I want to fetch all photos of user who is logged in to my app using facebook . 
I am getting 200 error code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fields", "user_photos");
    String id = com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId();
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/" + id + "/photos",
            bundle,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonPhotos = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                        Log.d("", "onCompleted: ");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

Response

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[]}, error: null}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 200 means that your request is OK.

You need https://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/albums?access_token=[AUTH_TOKEN] to get JSON array of all the albums of a user.

You will get three important things from here id - album id, name - album name, and type - album type.

The permission required is user_photos

Profile Pictures are under "Profile Pictures" album. To get to profile album, you need to look into albums array, iterate through the JSON result-set, until you get an album with name = Profile Pictures and type = profile. Get id of this object. This is the profile pictures album.

Now you can access it similar to you access any other album. That is, https://graph.facebook.com/[ALBUM_ID]/photos?access_token=[AUTH_TOKEN] this will list all the profile pictures of the user ever uploaded.

refer: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the user give you permission for the photos?